# User Control inherit from ListBox in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to make a user Control in WPf with same properties and events like ListBox.(can add items , remove them , selecting ,...)

on way in windows App is use a user control which is inherit form ListBox. but in WPF I don't know **how make User Control inherit from ListBox** (or other WPF Control)!!!

I write this code but it had an exception

```
 public partial class InboxListItem : ListBox
{
    public InboxListItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

and It's Xaml file

```
<UserControl 
x:Class="ListBoxControl.InboxListItem"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:myTypes="clr-namespace:ListBoxControl"
/>
```

Comment: I do believe you can just change the UserControl tag to a ListBox tag.

Comment: It possible even with define a 'listbox in UC', And define event, method and property for doing same thing in listbox.

Comment: Yes and you could add your own. Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201343/wpf-custom-usercontrol-that-includes-a-control-versus-inherits-a-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant make a UserControl inherit from ListBox. What you want is a CusomControl, and the xaml will traditionally live in Themes\Generic.xaml  Keep in mind that you have to register the default style.  Of course, you can just use the one provided by ListBox, if you want.
You should check [this article](http://pavanpodila.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!9C9E888164859398!135.entry), it provides some good information as well as links to more articles.